# Xcode 8 UI bug when creating New File

Tags: xcode, user-interface, xcode8

Screen shot link is attached

[image: Image link]

I updated to macOS Sierra and Xcode updated itself too. Then this issue started appearing. Is this only with me or someone else also facing this? Or anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me as well.
I observed that it happens when we have both, Xcode 7 and Xcode 8 installed at the same time on sierra. Please find a similar create a new project screen issue below:
[image]

Comment: How can Xcode 7 and 8 can be there simultaneously? And did you managed to fix it ?

Comment: Name one Xcode differently like Xcode 7 as "Xcode7" and reported an issue to Apple but didn't manage to fix it

Comment: Also try reinstalling Xcode 8 after uninstalling all Xcode components including all versions of command line tools

Comment: I have that bug too!