# New file screen misaligned in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode7.3.1.When i click  **File-> New->File** option from Xcode menu and i choose **Cocoa Touch Class** then a screen appear like the following screen.Its not aligned properly.I think this appear after installing Xcode8 on my Mac.This issue also appeared in Xcode8.Please go through following screen.How to solve this issue?[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205491/xcode-8-ui-bug-when-creating-new-file